# Trying to remove all text except for IPs, data is in a file I downloaded

Tags: scripts, text-processing, grep

This is what I normally use to normalize the data, but it is not working. I need to keep only the IPs, one IP per line, and everything else must go. I'm using this in an .sh shell script.

---

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+(/[0-9]+[^\# ]+)?' |\
        sort -V | uniq >> ipban/threat-50.txt

# Format: IP # ThreatLevel ThreatLevel Timestamp CountryCode
104.218.166.164 # 100 2023-01-20T01:33:10Z VN
61.240.137.169 # 100 2023-01-27T00:35:06Z CN
42.119.111.155 # 100 2023-01-20T00:25:25Z VN
190.137.180.107 # 100 2023-01-09T03:28:00Z AR
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it is "not working"? Is it failing to match things that it should, or matching things that it should not? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named input.txt which contains the following example data that you downloaded.

```
# Format: IP # ThreatLevel ThreatLevel Timestamp CountryCode
104.218.166.164 # 100 2023-01-20T01:33:10Z VN
61.240.137.169 # 100 2023-01-27T00:35:06Z CN
42.119.111.155 # 100 2023-01-20T00:25:25Z VN
190.137.180.107 # 100 2023-01-09T03:28:00Z AR
```

Run the following commands to create a file named threat-50.txt and append the output list of unique IPs to threat-50.txt:

```
touch threat-50.txt
cat input.txt | grep -oE '[0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+(/[0-9]+[^\# ]+)?' | sort -V | uniq >> threat-50.txt
```

Results of `cat threat-50.txt` :

```
42.119.111.155
61.240.137.169
104.218.166.164
190.137.180.107
```

Comment: I know this is a useless use of cat, but I indifferently used it anyway because it's easier to read that way.